# Python and pandas: is df["colName"] exactly equivalent to df.loc[:,"colName"]?

Tags: python, pandas

I've tested a lot of scenarios and in every one of them, `df['colName']` has outputted the same thing as `df.loc[:,'colName']`.

I'm just wanting to be sure that these really are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Yes, they are equal.

Comment: Do you want to know if they are the same semantically? Or the same path executed inside Pandas with similar side effects?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, they do the same thing.**

`df['colName']` will return the column specified in the square brackets, 
and `df.loc['rowName']` will return the row specified in the square brackets.
`df.loc['row1Name':'row2Name','colName']` will return all the elements of the column
specified in the brackets, from the first row specified to the last row specified.

`df.loc[:,'colName']` is basically telling python to return all the elements from the column specied
from all the rows, and so, it returns the whole column.

*Note that the parsing process may differ, one way may be more efficient than the other.*

Comment: Same semantically, true, but are they go along the same code path in Pandas? With the same side effects? My suspicion, `df.loc[:,'colName']` would have a bit different code path with more memory consumption

Answer (score 0):

They're the same in terms of providing output but have a performance difference. Try with the following example and observe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"colName": range(1000000)}, index=range(1000000))
print("with .loc: ", timeit.timeit('df.loc[:, "colName"]', globals=globals()))
print("without .loc: ", timeit.timeit('df["colName"]', globals=globals()))
```